# Why is edit() causing traceback?

Tags: python

Thank you so much for your help guys, I am in Grade 10 computer programming and yes this is my final assessment. I followed your suggestions and fixed my code.. but have one last thing that I would like to add, yet it seems to not be able to be found anywhere else. After the while loop for choice1, and if the input is "N", then I would like the program to end. But, when it does so, the output is

```
Okay, have a good day!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Zac_R/Documents/School/Grade 10/Computer Science/H1Z1 Text  
    Adventure.py", line 224, in 0
builtins.SystemExit:
```

Is there anyway to remove this so that it just says "Okay, have a good day!"?

Lastly, when I say "Please enter a valid command!", the type cursor moves to the next line (**) rather than staying where I want it (*). For example:

Please enter a valid command! [Y/N]: *
**

Code Below For Reference:

```
import time
import random
from sys import exit


def play ():

    # Health variables
    userHealth = 20
    zombieHealth = 15

    # This is the actual game
    print ( "{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}" )
    print ( "{------------=[Entering The Apocalypse!]=------------}" )
    print ( "{----------------------=[H1Z1]=----------------------}" )
    print ( "{---------------=[Made by: Zac Roter]=---------------}" )
    print ( "{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}" ) 
    time.sleep (1)

    print ( "You wake up in a small hospital room. You do not remember how you got here..." )
    time.sleep (1)

    print ( "It is dark and you can only make out a stick on the ground." )
    time.sleep (1)

    choice2 = input( "Do you take it? [Y/N]: " ) 

    # Stick taken
    if (choice2 == "Y"):
        print ( "Stick obtained!" )
        stick = 1


    # Stick not taken
    else:
        print ( "You did not take the stick" )
        stick = 0


    print ( "As you walk towards the only exit, you hear a faint voice ahead. " )
    time.sleep (1)

    choice3 = input( "Do you approach the voice? [Y/N]: " ) 

    # Approach zombie
    if (choice3 == "Y"):
        print ( "You approach the sound..." )
        time.sleep (1)
        print ( "As you get closer, you begin to make out the source of the sound was from a zombie!")
        choice4 = input( "Do you try to fight it? [Y/N]: ") 

        # Fight zombie
        if (choice4 == "Y"):

            # With stick
            if (stick == 1):
                print ( "You only have a stick to fight with!" )
                time.sleep (1)
                print ( "You swiftly strike the zombie in the leg to slow it down." )
                time.sleep (1)
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                    Loading...                  ")
                print ("         STICK DOES 2-8 DAMAGE PER TURN         ")
                print ("        ZOMBIE DOES 1-6 DAMAGE PER TURN         ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(1)    
                while (zombieHealth <= 0 and userHealth <= 0):
                    zombieHealth = zombieHealth - int(random.randint(2,9) )
                    userHealth = userHealth - int(random.randint(1,7) )
                    print ("Zombie has...", zombieHealth, "health left!" )
                    print ("You have...", userHealth, "health left!" )
                    time.sleep (1)

                if (zombieHealth <= 0 and userHealth > 0):
                    print ( "You have killed the zombie!" )

                if (userHealth <= 0 and zombieHealth > 0):
                    print ( "The zombie has killed you!" )
                    playagain()

                if (userHealth <= 0 and zombieHealth <= 0):
                    print ( "You kill the zombie, but you die of the zombie bite." )
                    playagain()

            # Without stick
            else:
                print ( "You don't have anything to fight with!" )
                time.sleep(1)
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                print ("                    Loading...                  ")
                print ("          HANDS DO 1-6 DAMAGE PER TURN          ")
                print ("        ZOMBIE DOES 1-6 DAMAGE PER TURN         ")
                print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                time.sleep(1)    
                while (zombieHealth > 0 and userHealth > 0):
                    zombieHealth = zombieHealth - int(random.randint(1,7) )
                    userHealth = userHealth - int(random.randint(1,7) )
                    print ("Zombie has...", zombieHealth, "health left!" )
                    print ("You have...", userHealth, "health left!" )
                    time.sleep (1)

                    if (zombieHealth <= 0 and userHealth > 0):
                        print ( "You have killed the zombie!" )

                    elif (userHealth <= 0 and zombieHealth > 0):
                        print ( "The zombie has killed you!" )
                        playagain()

                    else:
                        print ( "You kill the zombie, but you die of the zombie bite." )
                        playagain()






        #Don't fight zombie         
        else:            
            print ( "You choose not to fight the zombie." )
            time.sleep(1)
            print ( "As you turn away, it sprints and kills you!!!" )
            playagain()



    # Don't approach zombie
    else:
        print ( "As you turn away, a zombie sprints and kills you!!!" )
        playagain()


    print ( "Finally, you reach the exit to open doors to an unidentifiable world." )
    time.sleep (1)

    print ( "After a small victory, you hear the sounds of more zombies coming towards you from all angles." )
    time.sleep (1)

    print ( "Suddenly an SUV drives over the zombies in front of you!" )
    time.sleep (1)

    print ( "[Driver]: Get in, dammit!" )
    time.sleep (1)

    choice5 = input( "Do you get in the SUV? [Y/N]: " )
    time.sleep (1)

    # Enter SUV

    if (choice5 == "Y"):
        print ( "As you enter the SUV, the driver injects you with a syringe." )
        playagain()


    else: 
        print ( "You decline his offer, and as the SUV drives away, the zombies devour your remains." )
        playagain()


# The play again option that occurs after every user death
def playagain ():

    print ( "Thank you for playing H1Z1, by Zac Roter." )
    choice6 = input( "Would you like to play again? [Y/N]: " ) 

    if (choice6 == "Y"):
        play()

    if (choice6 == "N"):
        print ( "Okay, have a good day!" )
        exit()

    while (choice6 != "Y" or "N"):
        print ( "Please enter a valid command! [Y/N]: " )
        choice6 = input()

        if (choice1 == "Y"):
            print ( "Starting game..." )
            play()

        elif (choice1 == "N"):
            print ( "Okay, have a good day!" )
            exit()

# The main menu of the program
print ( "{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}" )
print ( "{-------------------=[Welcome To]=-------------------}" )
print ( "{----------------------=[H1Z1]=----------------------}" )
print ( "{---------------=[Made by: Zac Roter]=---------------}" )
print ( "{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}" )
time.sleep (1)


name = input( "Greetings survivor, what is your name?: " )
time.sleep (1)

print ( "Welcome "+name+", to H1Z1!" )
time.sleep (1)

print ( "The objective of this game is to survive in a zombie apocalypse." )
time.sleep (1)

choice1 = input( "Would you like to play? [Y/N]: " )

if (choice1 == "Y"):
    print ( "Starting game..." )
    play()

if (choice1 == "N"):
    print ( "Okay, have a good day!" )
    exit()


while (choice1 != "Y" or "N" ):
    print ( "Please enter a valid command! [Y/N]: " )
    choice1 = input()

    if (choice1 == "Y"):
        print ( "Starting game..." )
        play()

    elif (choice1 == "N"):
        print ( "Okay, have a good day!" )
        exit()
```

You guys rock!

Comment: Your combat sequences appear to be recursive (I didn't read the entire thing though) but you should be using `if` then `elif` then `else` statements there. Final project for programming class? What grade is this?

Comment: Are the 3 `if` statements supposed to be in your `while` loop? Otherwise, you've got an error with indentation/

Comment: Is your question "why is `exit()` causing a traceback?"  If so, that should be the title of the question....

Comment: Are you running this in Idle?

Comment: I am running it in Wing101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyse this:

```
>>> def a():
...    print("Type something: ")
...    a = input()
...
>>> a()
Type something: 
La la la la la la # That's my input
```

`print`ing in Python 3 is a function, with multiple hidden parameters that you'll rarely (if ever) enter. If you type `help(print)` in your interpreter, it explains it pretty well:

```
print(...)
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

The point of interest here lies in this part: `end = '\n'`. Inside the function, this is what really happens:

```
print my string, and add the "end" value. Flush to the screen (writing to the screen)
```

You have two options:

Change the `end` keyword argument when calling `print`:

```
print("Enter a valid command!", end = "")
choice6 = input()
```

Or remove the `print` call altogether. Put the string inside your `input`.

```
choice6 = input("Enter a valid command! ")
```

This will result in:

```
Enter a valid command! Never! # "Never!" is my input
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of choice1 is not getting updated inside the while-loop, so choice1 will remain something other than "Y", "y", "N", or "n". You need to fetch the input from the user again, so that this variable gets updated. Something like:

```
while(choice1 != "Y" or "y" or "N" or "n"):
    print("Please enter a valid command!")
    choice1 = input()
```